# Sonatype Nexus: Unexpected value of <latest> tag in "maven-metadata.xml"

Tags: maven, nexus, sonatype, maven-metadata

I'm using Sonatype Nexus v2.3.1-01 and I've got a problem with the value of the `<latest>` tag. I thought this value would become updated every time I upload a newer version of an artifact.

Now I had a look at the `<latest>` values for a couple of artifacts that **all have had new versions deployed to Nexus yesterday**. Result:

- `<latest>` fields of **some** artifacts hold version values from yesterday (what I expected)
- `<latest>` fields of **some** artifacts hold values a bit older (couple of days)
- `<latest>` fields of **some** artifacts hold values a month old or even older

So I guess there's either something wrong about my understanding of this  tag or something's wrong about by setup/configuration. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 2):

The [Nexus FAQ](https://docs.sonatype.com/display/SPRTNXOSS/Nexus+FAQ#NexusFAQ-Q.The%22latest%22and%22release%22tagsinmavenmetadata.xmlarenotbeingupdatedafterdeployingartifacts) describes when LATEST/RELEASE is set. Latest is only used (and updated) for maven plugins.

Answer (score 2):

"LATEST" only works reliably with group repos. See - http://www.blackpepper.co.uk/posts/nexus-support-for-latest-version